# I have 30 photos, which I want to sort into 2 categories. Either one can be empty. How many ways can I sort these photos, order matters?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I know the answer is $\binom{31}{1}\cdot30!$, and I understand the reasoning as organizing $30!$ ways and then $\binom{31}{1}$ places to put the delimiter.

Why is it not $2^{30}\cdot30!$ That is, each of the $30$ photos has $2$ choices, organize $30!$ ways.

Comment: "Order matters" can be interpreted in (at least) two ways: There may be an a priori ordering of the $30$ pictures, or there may be first a sorting of the pictures into two categories, and within each of these categories the pictures are ordered a posteriori.

Answer (score 2):

You are right there are $2^{30}$ ways to separate them into two piles, but then you only have to order each pile. If the left pile has $19$ photos, there are $19!$ ways to order that one and $11!$ ways to order the other, but $19!11! \neq 30!$ some of the ordering is done by the split into piles.

Answer (score 0):

Once all the items are assigned to one of the categories $(2^{30})$ there aren't $30!$ ways to arrange them.  There aren't 30 positions available to each item.  Only the number of items in their category.  For example, if 29 items are in one category and 1 in the other.  The lone item in the second category only has $1!$ spot it could be "arranged" in.  Not 30.